# Nagios nrpe no handler for command

Tags: nagios, nrpe

so i have started setting up Nagios on our network and have the below issue :
No handler for command CheckDisk . This happens no matter what command i run. 
( full command i have been running is /.check-nrpe -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -c CheckDisk )
if i do just a ./check-nrpe -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx i get the following :

I (0,4,1,102 2013-07-15) seem to be doing fine...

i am running the NSClient++ on a 2008R2 Server. 
This is the output from the "nscp.exe test" command

```
d vice\logger_impl.cpp:420  Creating logger: console

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:386  NSClient++ 0,4,1,102 2013-07-15 x64 Loading settings and 
logger...

d ngs_manager_impl.cpp:162  Boot.ini found in: C:/Program Files/NSClient++//boot.ini

d ngs_manager_impl.cpp:178  Boot order: ini://${exe-path}/nsclient.ini

d ngs_manager_impl.cpp:181  Activating: ini://${exe-path}/nsclient.ini

d ngs_manager_impl.cpp:73   Creating instance for: ini://${exe-path}/nsclient.ini

d mpl/settings_ini.hpp:303  Reading INI settings from: C:/Program Files/NSClient++
//nsclient.ini

d mpl/settings_ini.hpp:253  Loading: C:/Program Files/NSClient++//nsclient.ini

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:397  NSClient++ 0,4,1,102 2013-07-15 x64 booting...

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:398  Booted settings subsystem...

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:465  On crash: restart: NSClientpp

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:477  Archiving crash dumps in: C:/Program Files/NSClient++//crash-
dumps

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:544  booting::loading plugins

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:306  Found: CheckDisk

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:306  Found: CheckEventLog

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:306  Found: CheckExternalScripts

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:306  Found: CheckHelpers

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:306  Found: CheckNSCP

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:306  Found: CheckSystem

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:306  Found: CheckWMI

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:306  Found: NRPEServer

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:867  addPlugin(C:/Program Files/NSClient++//modules/CheckDisk.dll 
as )

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:867  addPlugin(C:/Program Files/NSClient++//modules/CheckEventLog.dll as )

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:867  addPlugin(C:/Program Files/NSClient++//modules/CheckExternalScripts.dll as )

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:867  addPlugin(C:/Program Files/NSClient++//modules/CheckHelpers.dll as )

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:867  addPlugin(C:/Program Files/NSClient++//modules/CheckNSCP.dll as )

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:867  addPlugin(C:/Program Files/NSClient++//modules/CheckSystem.dll as )

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:867  addPlugin(C:/Program Files/NSClient++//modules/CheckWMI.dll as )

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:867  addPlugin(C:/Program Files/NSClient++//modules/NRPEServer.dll as )

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:844  Loading plugin: CheckDisk

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:844  Loading plugin: Event log Checker.

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:844  Loading plugin: Check External Scripts

d kExternalScripts.cpp:99   No wrappings found (adding default: vbs, ps1 and bat)

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:844  Loading plugin: Helper function

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:844  Loading plugin: Check NSCP

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:844  Loading plugin: CheckSystem

d stem\CheckSystem.cpp:158  Found alternate key for uptime: \2\674

d stem\CheckSystem.cpp:169  Found alternate key for memory commit limit: \4\30

d stem\CheckSystem.cpp:180  Found alternate key for memory commit bytes: \4\26

d stem\CheckSystem.cpp:191  Found alternate key for cpu: \238(_total)\6

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:844  Loading plugin: CheckWMI

d tem\PDHCollector.cpp:94   Loading counter: cpu = \238(_total)\6

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:844  Loading plugin: NRPE server

d tem\PDHCollector.cpp:94   Loading counter: memory commit bytes = \4\26

d erver\NRPEServer.cpp:133  Allowed hosts definition: 192.168.1.245(255.255.255.255)

d tem\PDHCollector.cpp:94   Loading counter: memory commit limit = \4\30

d tem\PDHCollector.cpp:94   Loading counter: uptime = \2\674

d de\socket/server.hpp:126  Binding to: [::]:5666(ipv6)

d de\socket/server.hpp:162  Attempting to bind to: :5666

e de\socket/server.hpp:165  Failed to bind: Only one usage of each socket address 
(protocol/network address/port) is nor
mally permitted

d rvice\NSClient++.cpp:616  NSClient++ - 0,4,1,102 2013-07-15 Started!
l ce\simple_client.hpp:32   Enter command to inject or exit to terminate...

exit
```

Anyone got any ideas on what is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

turns out i was using the wrong commands

Comment: Telling us the wrong commands might assist other users in future and make this an answer.